# Testing NodeJs with Mocha/Sinon - Sails

Tags: node.js, unit-testing, sails.js, mocha.js

I'm relatively new to nodejs and sailsjs framework, and I really enjoy write code with it, but coming from a PHP background I found testing nodeJs a bit weird.

I'm trying to test with `mocha` and `sinon` the method `login` of my `AuthService`, but being not expert I would need an example on how do you achieve a successful test for it , unfortunately documentation online is still a bit poor an example will be a lots useful thanks!

```
login: function(username,password,callback) {

        User.findOneByUsername(username, function(err,user){

            // If has some error
            if (err) { return callback(err) }

            // if the user is not found with that username
            if (!user) { return callback(err,false); }

            // if is found we match the password
            bcrypt.compare(password, user.password, function (err, res) {

                if (!res || err) return callback(err,false);

                return callback(err,true,user);
            });
        });
    }
```

If you can make light on this will be really appreciated

Answer (score 1):

Check we.js example for how to setup you tests:

link: https://github.com/wejs/we-example/tree/master/test ( with only "headless browser" tests now )

For integration and unit tests with supertest check: https://github.com/wejs/we/tree/emberjsDev/tests

Comment: Wow this resource is pretty good thanks so much! There are any else like this? I really want to test properly my Js ServerSide code.

Comment: I need to update my code in the new structure we.js that uses the resources of sails.js 0.10.x ... so I have that part of serverside ready ... but you can get links that i send and make you tests ...